# How to deploy a .war file into jboss server running in AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jboss, wildfly, war

I created a JBoss EAP instance on AWS-EC2 (following [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/deploying_red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform_on_amazon_ec2/index#launching_instance_on_amazon_ec2_console) guide), and now I'm trying to deploy a simple hello-world application into that.

I've copied the .war file into the /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/standalone/deployments folder, and then I ran the standalone.sh in the /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/bin folder, and got this log:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

15:11:14,196 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.6.Final-redhat-00001
15:11:14,830 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001
15:11:14,854 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final-redhat-1
15:11:15,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) starting
15:11:17,070 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.6.1.Final-redhat-00001
15:11:18,572 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
15:11:18,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
15:11:18,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
15:11:18,905 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.6.5.Final-redhat-00001
15:11:18,930 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.5.Final-redhat-00001
15:11:19,070 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
15:11:19,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
15:11:19,114 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
15:11:19,123 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
15:11:19,177 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
15:11:19,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
15:11:19,218 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
15:11:19,225 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 2 core threads with 16 task threads based on your 1 available processors
15:11:19,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
15:11:19,263 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
15:11:19,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
15:11:19,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.6.1.SP2-redhat-00001
15:11:19,359 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
15:11:19,435 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.8.Final-redhat-1
15:11:19,569 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001 starting
15:11:19,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001)
15:11:19,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-3
15:11:19,787 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
15:11:19,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
15:11:19,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
15:11:19,958 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
15:11:19,947 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
15:11:20,062 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
15:11:20,082 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 4 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
15:11:20,601 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
15:11:20,708 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
15:11:20,916 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
15:11:20,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
15:11:21,208 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
15:11:21,218 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/standalone/deployments
15:11:21,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
15:11:21,236 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "hello-world.war" (runtime-name: "hello-world.war")
15:11:21,471 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
15:11:21,630 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final-redhat-00001 (Apache CXF 3.2.5.redhat-00001)
15:11:23,358 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Estrella Galicia' 9.3.3.Final-redhat-00001
15:11:23,971 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
15:11:24,233 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/hello-world' for server 'default-server'
15:11:24,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "hello-world.war" (runtime-name : "hello-world.war")
15:11:24,413 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
15:11:24,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
15:11:24,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:11:24,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) started in 10933ms - Started 404 of 589 services (326 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

As I'm not seeing any ERROR, I think everything went ok, and my app is ready to run. Although when I do a curl, this is what I'm getting

curl http://127.0.0.1:9990/hello-world
Error404 - Not Found

And if I do just curl http://127.0.0.1:9990, then nothing happens.

Also, when I try to use my public DNS of the instance, and do like *publicDNS*.compute.amazonaws.com/hello-world the page gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Am I missing some step here?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be on port 8080. Port 9990 is the management port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access your web application on the wrong port. 9990 is the admin port, where admin console is deployed. The default port for web applications in wildfly is 8080. So try to do a curl on the ec2 instance

http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello-world

Answer (score 0):

Also, the second problem I had, the instance not being reachable trhough the public DNS I did the following and it works:

As the app server is JBoss 7.1 standalone, I had to edit the standalone.xml and replace this:

```
<interface name="public">
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
</interface>
```

with this:

```
<interface name="public">
<any-address/>
</interface>
```